# Can´t Create Virtual network gateway on Azure

Tags: networking, vpn, azure-virtual-network

I´m trying to connect my local network to Azure VPC, but I´m having trouble creating a "Virtual network gateway" I´m following this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal), but on step 4 he ask me create a "Virtual network gateway" which I can´t do because he don´t detect my virtual network ("No virtual networks found in the selected subscription and location 'Brazil South'."). I have already created "the gateway subnet" manually but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas?

This is my configuration so far and also a print of the error.

- VNet Name: SPI_VPC
- Address Space: 10.11.0.0/16
- Subnets:

  - default: 10.11.0.0/24
  - GatewaySubnet: 10.11.255.0/27
- Location: Brazil South

**[Prints Virtual Gateway Error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfvicvgjlmn4a4e/VPCError.zip?dl=0)**

Comment: well, you obviously do not have a network in brazil south...

Comment: Yes I do, my VPC was created on this region.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusBianchiSantos Please ensure you create Virtual Network firstly, you could check my answer. When you create Virtual network, you should select suitable Address space.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I just update my current configurations so you can see.

Comment: Try to delete Gateway subnet, the error is same?

Comment: Could you show the virtual network sceen picture in your question? I want to do some check to kown the root reason.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Just added all my SS's to the post in the same link

Comment: Sorry, I  can't see it. Could you check it.

Comment: Is in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfvicvgjlmn4a4e/VPCError.zip?dl=0 I can't upload more images on the post so I had to zip and put on dropbox

Comment: @MarcusViniciusBianchiSantos I checked it carefully and found it your Virtual Network is a classic Virtual Network. It can not be selected by ARM Gateway.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT thanks a lot that worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you create Virtual Network, please ensure subnet address ranges don't use all address space. Because when you create VPN gateway, it needs create a gateway subnet. If you create Virtual Network like below:

[image]

when you create VPN gateway, you could not select the Virtual Network.

You should create Virtual Network like below:

[image]

Update:

Your Virtual Network is a classic Virtual Network. ARM Virtual Network Gateway only could select ARM mode Virtual Network. You could check your Virtual Network on Azure Portal.
[image]

You should create ARM mode Virtual Network.

[image]